# In a Xamarin Forms application. What's a Styles.xcassets file in the iOS project used for?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

My application has one of these files but it doesn't seem to do anything and when I click on it, then it shows as empty.

Answer (score 0):

That is an Asset Catalog Image Sets

> Asset Catalog Image Sets - Use Asset Catalog Image Sets to manage and
>   group all version of a given image asset required by an app.

You can add images to your iOS solution, using Resources, or creating a Catalog Image Set.

You can read the [official Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Xcode/Reference/xcode_ref-Asset_Catalog_Format/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40015170-CH18-SW1)

Comment: That looks like an Assets.xcassets file.  My question was about Styles.xcassets file

Answer (score 0):

There is no default file called `Styles.xcassets` in the iOS project. And I think this is a normal `Asset Catalog Image Sets` file created by someone.

In an iOS project, the is a default `Asset Catalog Image Sets` called `Assets.xcassets` file and manager your image there.

Also, instead of using the `Assets.xcassets`, you can create more ...`.xcassets` to manager your images. It can be more clear and is easier to distinguish different kinds of images.

For example, if there is a `Styles.xcassets`, you can put all images of style into this file. You can also create a `Home.xcassets` there to put all images in the `homePage` there.

Hope you understand `What's a Styles.xcassets file in the iOS project used for` now.